# Работа с объектом, массивом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Всем привет, ребят, подскажите как правильно работать с объектом который я получаю по API
В консоли получаю такой объект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как его правильно распарсить, что бы потом можно было внутри этого объекта делать поиск, например разбить его на массив что бы внутри него искать.
Код ниже

```
  $(function() {
            var settings = {
                "url": "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/",
                "method": "POST",
                "crossDomain": true,
                "async": true,
                "timeout": 0,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                "data": JSON.stringify({
                    "modelName": "AddressGeneral",
                    "calledMethod": "getWarehouses",
                    "methodProperties": {
                        "Language": "ru",
                        "CityName": "Киев"
                    },
                    "apiKey": "d1ac5ac8d6ac6ed4929faf01e3698856"
                }),
            };

            $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            });
        });
введите сюда код
```

Comment: это  вид обычного массива  с большим числом элементов  в консоли. с ним собственно и нужно работать как с обычным массивом.  вид такой отображается для удобства

Comment: Это массив длиной 474, если откроете, например, 0-й элемент, то можете посмотреть структуру объектов. Исходя из структуры делать все операции с массивом типа `filter()` или `find()`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните проблему, которую Вы решаете: что на входе, что на выходе?

Comment: я хочу реализовать поиск города и отделения через typehead https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/